# Wp_insert_term doesn't work from separate file with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have code that works good in main plugin file:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Id_CRM_Contacts_User_Cpt' ) ) {

class Id_CRM_Contacts_User_Cpt {

    function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'custom_post_type' ) );
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'create_first_contact_status' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'custom_post_type' ) );
    }

    public function custom_post_type() {

            $labels = array(
                'name'              => esc_html_x( 'Statuses', 'taxonomy general name', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'singular_name'     => esc_html_x( 'Status', 'taxonomy singular name', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'search_items'      => esc_html__( 'Search Statuses', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'all_items'         => esc_html__( 'All Statuses', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'parent_item'       => esc_html__( 'Parent Status', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => esc_html__( 'Parent Status:', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'edit_item'         => esc_html__( 'Edit Status', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'update_item'       => esc_html__( 'Update Status', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'add_new_item'      => esc_html__( 'Add New Status', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'new_item_name'     => esc_html__( 'New Status Name', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                'menu_name'         => esc_html__( 'Statuses', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
            );

            $args = array(
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'query_var'         => true,
                'rewrite'           => array(
                    'slug'  => 'contacts/status',
                    'feeds' => false,
                    'feed'  => false,
                ),
                'labels'            => $labels,
                'sort'              => true,
                'capabilities     ' => array(
                    'manage_terms' => 'edit_user_status',
                    'edit_terms'   => 'edit_user_status',
                    'delete_terms' => 'edit_user_status',
                    'assign_terms' => 'edit_user_status',
                ),
            );

            register_taxonomy( 'user_status', 'user_contact', $args );

            
            register_post_type(
                'user_contact',
                array(
                    'public'          => true,
                    'has_archive'     => true,
                    'rewrite'         => array(
                        'slug'  => 'contacts',
                        'feeds' => false,
                        'feed'  => false,
                    ),
                    'label'           => esc_html__( 'Contacts', 'idcrm_contacts' ),
                    'supports'        => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'revisions', 'author', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
                    'taxonomies'      => array( 'user_status', 'user_source ' ),
                    'show_ui'         => true,
                    'show_in_menu'    => 'idcrm-contacts',
                    'capability_type' => array( 'user_contact', 'user_contacts' ),
                    'map_meta_cap'    => true,
                )
            );
    }
    /** Create first contact status */
    public function create_first_contact_status() {
        $term_check = term_exists( esc_html__( 'Leads', 'idcrm_contacts' ) );

        if ( empty( $term_check ) ) {
            wp_insert_term( esc_html__( 'Leads', 'idcrm_contacts' ), 'user_status' );
        }
     }
   }
 }
 if ( class_exists( 'Id_CRM_Contacts_User_Cpt' ) ) {
    $id_crm_contacts_user_cpt = new Id_CRM_Contacts_User_Cpt();
    $id_crm_contacts_user_cpt->register();
 }
```

But if I move it to separate file it doesn't work. I try to fire it from main file like this:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Id_CRM_Contacts_User_Cpt' ) ) {
 require IDCRMCONTACTS_PATH . 'includes/class-id-crm-contacts-user.php';
}
```

I don't want to use 'default_term' because it creates every time then user change it. And don't want to use 'init' the same. It should creates at plugin activation only. Is it possible to insert term to custom taxonomy from other file?

Comment: what is `IDCRMCONTACTS_PATH`? `__FILE__` must be the main plugin file, if you move your class then you need to provide it with that value or you'll get the wrong value for `__FILE__`

Comment: IDCRMCONTACTS_PATH - url to file with class. If I use `require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-id-crm-contacts-user.php';` it's still doesn't work.

Comment: you can't use `__FILE__` in `register_activation_hook` if it's not the main plugin file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`register_activation_hook` requires the main plugin file as its first parameter, and `__FILE__` is an easy way to get this.

But by moving this code into a sub-file you've changed the value of `__FILE__` and it no longer matches your plugin main file ( `includes/class-id-crm-contacts-user.php` is not the main file of your plugin with the plugin header that got activated ).

Instead, you must pass the value as a parameter. This will be difficult as you have chosen to both define, use, and create objects in the same file. Instead if you move the creation of the object back out of the file, you'll be able to pass it the needed value via the constructor.